# Extend basis of a subspace to a basis of $\mathbb{C}^5$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $U$ be the subspace of $\mathbb{C}^5$ defined by
>   $$U = \{(z_1, z_2, z_3, z_4, z_5) \in \mathbb{C}^5: 6z_1 = z_2\;\wedge\;  z_3 + 2z_4 + 3z_5 =0 \}$$
>
> (a) Find a basis of $U$
>
> (b) Extend the basis in part(a) to a basis of $\mathbb{C}^5$.
>
> (c) Find a subspace $W$ of $\mathbb{C}^5$ such that $\mathbb{C}^5 = U \oplus W$

For part (a), by using two conditions, I find the basis of $U$ is $$\{(1,6,0,0,0), (0,0,-2,1,0), (0,0,-3,0,1)\}$$

But how can I extend it to a basis of $\mathbb{C}^5$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider any spanning set, for example, the standard vectors $\{e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4,e_5\}$. Call your three basis vectors as $v_1,v_2,v_3$. If $e_1$ is a linear combination of $v_i$'s then do not add $e_1$ to your list. If this is not the case , then  add $e_1$ to the list and so now it has four independent vectors. Can you continue?

For the next part, we already have a basis $\{v_1,v_2,v_3,e_k,e_m\}$ of $\Bbb C^5$ where $e_k$ and $e_m$ are standard vectors obtaining in the previous part. Now it is easy to check that $\text{span}(e_k,e_m)$ is the required $W$